# Incorrect parameter type for operator '+'. Expected Number, Date, Datetime, received Text

Tags: formula, formula-field, custom-report-type

[image: Attempted formula]

> Error: Invalid custom sumary formula definition: Incorrect parameter type for operator '+'. Expected Number, Date, Datetime, received Text.

I am trying to append %symbol after the field value for a custom report in salesforce. Any ideas how I can add this?

Comment: I afraid you cannot add from custom report. As we can only do Maths formula in custom reports. What you can do is add formla field in object and use it in report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add this in custom report. format for the formula in report in number/percent/currency. Need to create field

Comment: just added screenshot of the error, please look into it.

Comment: This seems to be the solution.